# Is there a POSIX way to get the starting time of a given PID from the shell?

Tags: timestamp, sh, posix, pid

I have a file whose content is `PID` <kbd>Tab</kbd> `STARTTIME` and I would like to know if that process is still alive.

I can check that a given PID is running with:

```bash
kill -0 "$pid" && echo alive
```

But it lacks the ability to differentiate between the real process and an other one that got the same PID.

So I though of using `ps`:

```bash
ps -o lstart= -p "$pid"
```

But it errputs:

```
ps: unknown output format: -o lstart
```

Is there a POSIX way to get the starting time (in seconds since EPOCH) of a given PID from the shell?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: My first target is AIX, but if I can find a satisfactory and portable solution then I'll use it on other OSs too

Comment: This might help as first step: `ps -o etime "$pid"`

Comment: On systems that support `/proc/...` you can alternatively store and compare the inode number of `/proc/PID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Cyrus pointed out, it's possible to use the output of `ps -o etime=` to calculate the starting time of a given PID:

<sub>**edit:** as @KamilCuk suggested, the functions now use a shell pipe instead of dealing with the `ps` call from inside `awk`.</sub>

```bash
# usage: starttime PID
starttime() {
    command -p ps -o etime= -p "$1" |
    command -p awk '
        BEGIN { srand(); timeofday = srand() }
        END {
            if (NF) {
                n = split($NF, a, "[:-]")
                print timeofday - a[n-3]*86400 - a[n-2]*3600 - a[n-1]*60 - a[n]
            } else
                exit 1
        }
    '
}
```

But it's more like an **approximation**, because when I compare it to the starting "date" provided by `ps -o lstart=` in Linux, I don't get identical results; as shown by the following script that outputs both values for all the running processes:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

starttime() { ... }

while read pid lstart
do
    t1=$(date -d "$lstart" +%s) &&
    t2=$(starttime "$pid") &&
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$t1" "$t2"
done < <(
    ps -o pid= -o lstart= -e
)
```

```
1681318132  1681318133
1681133418  1681133419
1681133418  1681133418
1681318132  1681318132
...
```

While the results are certainly different, the difference doesn't exceed 1 second; therefore, I think that we can still use `ps -o etime=` for checking that a process is alive **in an environment that doesn't require much precision** (for ex. a cron job). Here's a function that "allows" a ±1 second delta:

<sub>**tested on AIX/Solaris/macOS/FreeBSD/Linux**</sub>

```bash
# usage: is_alive PID STARTTIME
is_alive() {
    command -p ps -o etime= -p "$1" |
    command -p awk -v starttime="$2" '
        BEGIN { srand(); timeofday = srand() }
        END {
            n = split($NF, a, "[:-]")
            d = starttime - timeofday + a[n-3]*86400 + a[n-2]*3600 + a[n-1]*60 + a[n]
            exit( -1 < d || d > 1 )
        }
    '
}
```

Comment: `now = (srand() ? srand() : srand())` What does this line do? I do nt follow, why not just `ps -o etime "$pid" | awk 'parse it'`?

Comment: @KamilCuk `srand(); now = srand()` is for getting the "time-of-day" in any POSIX `awk`. The ternary operator is superfluous but does the same thing.

Comment: I first tried to use `ps | awk` but the code got messy (I didn't try to refactor it though); also, I'm not sure about the delay that a shell pipe might introduce; I'm trying to keep the timing of execution of `ps` and `srand();srand()` as close as possible.